# I/O using windowbuilder in eclipse for a java application

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I've never used java windowbuilder before, however I'm trying to test it with my program which performs operations on sets. It's a Gradle project. I wrote all classes in the default package (I knew that it's discouraged just when I was finished). The program reads a line of operations on sets, parses it and prints the result and keeps doing that while there is a new line input from the user. 
I'm trying to make a simple GUI for this program using windowbuilder but I can't figure out how to run the main class in the windowbuilder class and make it take input from a jtextfield and prints output.

My main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) { 
        new Main().start(); 
    } 

    private void start() { 
        hmap  = new HashMap<IdentifierInterface, SetInterface<BigInteger>>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  
        // While there is input, read line and parse it. 
        while (in.hasNextLine()) { 
            try { 
                String statement = in.nextLine(); 
                if (statement.trim().isEmpty()) { 
                    System.out.println("error, no statement"); 
                } else { 
                    Scanner statementScanner = new Scanner(statement); 
                    readStatement(statementScanner); 
                } 
            } catch (APException e) { 
                System.out.printf("%s\n", e.getMessage()); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

I made a new windowbuilder class, with the buttons and text fields, but I got stuck on how to run my main inside the windowbuilder. Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse RCP applications are OSGi plug-ins; they do not have a main() method.

Instead your Main class should look like this:

```
package com.myplugin;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Main implements BundleActivator {
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        // Copy your start logic here
    }
}
```

Then edit META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and set for example

```
Bundle-Activator: com.myplugin.Main
```

This makes your Main class the activator of the plug-in: start() will be invoked at load.

Comment: This seems way too advanced that what I can do. Could you guide through it? or maybe recommend an easier way to add a simple GUI to my main which takes input and gives output just like the console window?